# R Shiny - How to do multiple tasks at the same time in one session? Such as two calculations or two timer

Tags: r, shiny, parallel-processing

How can R(Shiny) perform multiple tasks at the same time?
For example have a "clock" or timer in your UI which keeps on ticking while having an another "ObserveEvent" trigger/calculation running?

See the following example in Shiny below. When you press "click", the clock freezes since R starts focussing on the for loop.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  h2(textOutput("currentTime")),
  actionButton("click","click")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$currentTime <- renderText({
    invalidateLater(1000, session)
    paste("The current time is", Sys.time())
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$click,{
    showNotification("Computation started!", type = "error")
    #Sys.sleep(2)
    for(i in 1:(8*10^7)) 1 + 1
    showNotification("Computation finished!", type = "error")
    
  })
  
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You have to run the computation in a different process. Find a nice explanation about how to do that in shiny [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/promises/vignettes/overview.html).